# Docker compose file for airflow 2 ( version 2.0.0 )

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker-compose, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am looking to write docker compose file to locally execute airflow in production similar environent.

For older airflow v1.10.14, docker compose is working fine. But same docker compose is not working for latest stable version, airflow scheduler & webservice is failing continuously. error message looks like unable to create audit tables.

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
 version: "2.1"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"

  scheduler:
    image: apache/airflow:1.10.14
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - webserver
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8793:8793"
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./airflow-logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5

  webserver:
    image: apache/airflow:1.10.14
    hostname: webserver
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./scripts:/opt/airflow/scripts
      - ./airflow-logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    entrypoint: ./scripts/airflow-entrypoint.sh
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5
```

`.env`:

```yaml
AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_DEFAULT_CONNECTIONS=False
AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgres+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow
AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY=81HqDtbqAywKSOumSha3BhWNOdQ26slT6K0YaZeZyPs=
AIRFLOW_CONN_METADATA_DB=postgres+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow
AIRFLOW_VAR__METADATA_DB_SCHEMA=airflow
AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__SCHEDULER_HEARTBEAT_SEC=10
```

`./scripts/airflow-entrypoint.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
airflow upgradedb
airflow webserver
```

Comment: Can you try changing `airflow upgradedb` to `airflow db upgrade` in entrypoint.sh?  `upgradedb` command should be removed in v2.0.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an official `docker-compose.yml` see [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml).

You will also find more information about docker and Kubernetes deployment in the [official docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html)

Comment: I am getting an unexpected error with this image 
67d927dd9b8a: Waiting
ERROR: error pulling image configuration: received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable

Comment: do you know if this is working for the latest version of airflow 2.0.2
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:|version|}

Answer (score 0):

Official docker image for Airflow version 2.0 is available now. Here is list of [2.0.0 docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/airflow/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=2.0.0)

Example docker image :

```
# example:
apache/airflow:2.0.0-python3.8
```

The below docker-compose handles

- airflow db schema upgrade
- admin user creation

Here is a version that I use:

```
version: "3.7"

# Common sections extracted out
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.0.0-python3.8}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    # Change log level when needed
    AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL: 'INFO'
  volumes:
    - ./airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
  depends_on:
    - postgres
    - redis
  networks:
      - default_net

volumes: 
  postgres-db-volume:

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    networks:
        - default_net

  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.10
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always
    networks:
        - default_net



  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # It is sufficient to run db upgrade and create admin user only from webserver service
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: 'yourAdminPass'
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'


  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    restart: always
    
networks:
    default_net:
      attachable: true
```

Comment: With this docker-compose I always get
airflow-worker_1     | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "airflow"
How i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

update docker-compose version to :version: "3.7"

Answer (score 0):

First run :

```
docker compose up airflow-init
```

Notice docker compose with space (instead of -)

and then :

```
docker compose up
```

it should work!