# Airflow 2.0 Docker setup

Tags: python-3.x, docker, airflow, airflow-2.x

Recently been trying to learn Airflow, but a majority of resources online depended on this repo `https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow` which unfortunately has been removed.

I am not familiar with docker so I'm just trying to set up locally and play around with Airflow.  I'm on a windows setup and have already gotten docker working on my computer.  Does Airflow have a quick-set-up file for a `docker-compose`? Or is there any other resources I can look at? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker compose file for airflow 2 ( version 2.0.0 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65889968/docker-compose-file-for-airflow-2-version-2-0-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently added a quick start guides to the official Apache Airflow documentation. Unfortunately, this guide has not been released yet. It will be released in Airflow 2.0.1.
For now, you can use the development version, and when a stable version is released it will be very easy for you to migrate. I don't expect any major changes to our docker-compose.yaml files.
http://apache-airflow-docs.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docs/apache-airflow/latest/start/docker.html

Answer (score 1):

Its a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65889968/docker-compose-file-for-airflow-2-version-2-0-0).
Use official official docker-compose.yml [see here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/docs/apache-airflow/start/docker-compose.yaml)