# azure-quickstart-templates for airflow 2

Tags: azure, docker, airflow, azure-container-instances, azure-rm-template

Few days back, I have installed airflow 1.X using the azure quick start template using https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/deploying-apache-airflow-in-azure-to-build-and-run-data-pipelines/

I am looking for a similar template to easily (just to try) deploy Airflow 2 on Azure.

I tried modifying the template from above link to point official Apache Airflow image and the airflow app keeps shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

•   Below is the link for the official docker image for Airflow version 2.0. You can replace the puckel/docker-airflow image tag in the container image source settings with the apache/airflow:2.0.0 below from docker hub.

https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/airflow/2.0.0/images/sha256-e973fef20d3be5b6ea328d2707ac87b90f680382790d1eb027bd7766699b2409?context=explore

•   Also, please refer the docker-compose.yaml file to implement the apache airflow 2.0 in proof-of-concept environment. It deploys the apache airflow 2.0 in azure to build and run data pipelines in celery executor mode with Azure Redis and PostgreSQL in cluster configuration.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/docs/apache-airflow/start/docker-compose.yaml

•   Please refer the below link for more information on this topic: -

[Docker compose file for airflow 2 ( version 2.0.0 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65889968/docker-compose-file-for-airflow-2-version-2-0-0)